# CKeditor in Jquery Simplemodal box

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, simplemodal

I am trying to use the SimpleModal plugin for jquery to load a popup div with a CKEditor in it, but when the modal box opens up, the CKeditor is all disabled and won't let me type text into it. I am using all default settings.
Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you initializing the CKEditor at the right time? From the [**simplemodal docs**](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/):

> onShow: Useful for binding events or any other actions you might want to perform after the modal dialog elements have been displayed. If you are including another plugin (TinyMCE, DatePicker, etc.) in a modal dialog, this is where you want to initialize that plugin.

And a second possibility, I'm not sure whether this will help you, but the JQuery UI modal dialog has a  [**similar problem**](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4727) showing CKEditor for which a [**patch**](http://dev.jqueryui.com/attachment/ticket/4727/dialog-patch.js) exists.

Comment: Thanks Pekka! That did the trick nicely.

Also, I didn't know about the UI modal dialog. Maybe that one would be better to use. You are a rock star!